# JSON.stringify() &quot &quot caterstrophy

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
connection.query( 'SELECT DeskName FROM desks WHERE stat = ?',["Booked"], function(err,   rows){
if(err) {
    throw err;
}else{
    try{
var toParse = new Array();
toParse = rows; 
res.render('workspaces.html',{myArray : JSON.stringify(toParse)});
```

i have this code here which its suppose to stringify the the values inside the array called toParse and pass it to an html page. But what i get after passing the sringified array is strange strings `"&quot;[&quot;MYRESULT&quot;[&quot;"` that encloses my results.

Below is my call in the HTML page:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){

alert( "<%= JSON.stringify(myArray) %>" );
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query function is retuning an array MYRESULT which contains the result set.

It would help if we could see what the query call was doing.

Try:

```
JSON.stringify(toParse.MYRESULT)
```

That is more likely to return what you are expecting

L

Comment: after trying JSON.stringify(toParse.MYRESULT) i get undefied error!  the query call returns &quot["&quot["&quot["&quot[" .

and this is how i have called it:
function myFunction(){

alert( "<%= JSON.stringify(myArray) %>" );

}